# Delete polygons from layer 1 with polygons from layer 2 based on a common attribute between both layers

Tags: r

I have two layers with a large number of polygons. Layer 1 are the polygons I want to crop (green border) and layer 2 are the clipping polygons (red border). Both layers have a common identifier in layer 1 is ID_1 and in layer 2 is ID_2.
[image]

The result should be that the polygon of layer 1 with ID_1 =1 is clipped by the polygon of layer 2 with ID_2=1 and so on with all matching polygons.
[image]

Comment: Its really useful if you can set up a sample data set for us to work on - saving everyone else the trouble of constructing some polygons to test methods on. You could maybe do that either with some R code that creates spatial objects or sharing a small sample data set as a GeoPackage.

Comment: The link to the layers:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/13M6uOKL23plD180ZGVhZq6imHlooBrs2/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably an "easier" way but by the time I've learnt how to do it the "easier" way I'd have written this:

```
chops <- function(c1, id1, c2, id2){

    ## split the spatial data frame by the ID column
    c1s = split(c1, c1[[id1]])
    c2s = split(c2, c2[[id2]])

    ## get the names of the splits
    n1 = names(c1s)
    n2 = names(c2s)

    ## match the splits from the first df to the second df
    m = match(n1, n2)

    ## for each of the matches, ie rows in the first data frame
    chopped = lapply(seq_along(m), function(i){

        ## get the first data frame item
        s1 = c1s[[i]]
        ## if it has any matches in the second...
        if(!is.na(m[i])){
            ## then get it
            s2 = c2s[[m[i]]]
            ## merge it and difference it to s1
            d = st_difference(s1, st_combine(s2))
            ## remove the redundant id column
            d[[id2]] = NULL
        }else{
            ## if there's nothing from second data frame to remove,
            ## return the first unchanged
            d = s1
        }
        return(d)
    })
    ## reassemble the list into a data frame and return
    do.call(rbind, chopped)
}
```

I think it works as described...

```
c1 = st_read("./capa_1.shp", quiet=TRUE)
c2 = st_read("./capa_2.shp", quiet=TRUE)
c12 = chops(c1, "ID_1", c2, "ID_2")
plot(c12)
```

[image]

You can't see the hole in polygons 1 and 2 but they are there:

```
plot(c12[1,])
```

[image]

```
plot(c12[2,])
```

[image]

I've tested this under a few other scenarios - I don't like ID variables being numeric since it gets confused with row numbers, so I replaced them with random alphabeticals, and changed the ordering and it still works.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. Regards

Comment: Can you mark it as the accepted answer? The The Algorithm knows it works perfectly too, for anyone else trying to do this.